# Does using Base64 over Hex for encoding my SHA-1 hash make it less secure?

Tags: hex, base64, sha1

A lot of the examples online show the hash as a hex representation, and they are typically custom implementations. Is there anything wrong with, or less secure about, using the Apache Commons Base64 encoding instead? When reading about encoding, it is usually within the realm of how to represent binary as text in XML, but does not necessarily discuss security concerns... just how the compression works.

On a related issue, why encode it all, since databases have binary types that could probably hold the encryption as binary? So if I'm storing a password, why not just store it in its native type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An encoding affects only the representation of the data, not its security. So, if you send an unencrypted password and use some form of encoding, you've not made it any more secure; likewise, if you take some highly encrypted text and then represent it in some encoding scheme, that won't make it any less secure, either. Typically, the reason to use this form of encoding is to send binary data using a protocol (such as SMTP), where the protocol is only capable of supporting 7-bit ASCII text. Another use is in URLs, where the set of characters that a URL can support is limited, but you might want to put arbitrarily complicated binary data in that URL (such as a validation signature of some sort).

Answer (score 3):

Not at all. It's just an encoding that represents the same bits in ASCII. It is mostly useful when you have to store or transmit binary data over communications paths designed to handle only text. Modern examples ore email and web interfaces. You also can't send the binary form to a terminal to view it, since it would result in garbage or strange terminal behavior.

If you can safely store the bits in a binary blob in a database there is no reason to encode in base64. But if you don't it would be harder to view it. You would have to convert it back to a text form first.

Answer (score 1):

Well we typically don't do too well reading binary, and hex is a better substitute for that. I wish you had linked to the articles you were referencing, so others could have a direct line on what it is you're forming an opinion from.

I don't understand *why* they would use Base64 over hex, but I'm assuming it's because hex is 16 digits and Base64 is a few more, thus generating a more compact version of the actual hash ;) ~ We humans tend to do better absorbing a small amount of data at a time.

Answer (score 1):

No, because Base64 is a 1:1 encoding (that is, for every input there is exactly one base64 encoded output, and vice-versa), base64 encoding a SHA1 hash is just as “secure” as a hex-encoded (or binary-encoded, for that matter) hash.

The encoding would only make a hash insecure if the encoding made it possible for multiple hashes to encode to the same string, or multiple strings to decode to the same hash.